# Access control different pages in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap

I have a Rails app that I need to put access control on. (Some pages can be accessed by everyone, some pages can only be accessed by certain LDAP groups of people, etc.) What's the best way to handle this access control?

One way is to have a `before_filter` in all of my controllers that checks, for each action, whether the user belongs to an LDAP group authorized for that action. (But this seems possibly messy.) Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this kind of thing with a authorization mechanism.

CanCan is really popular, and also quite simple: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

You can find other gems for handling authorization here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading [this book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) if you're new to Ruby On Rails. The section that talks about exactly what you need is [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec-access_control).

As far as I know, the before filter works perfectly, and isn't messy because it's handled in the controller for the page.